# Exim Configuration on Ubuntu 16.04, queue_per_connection

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, exim

Trying to set up Exim on Ubuntu 16.04, and I'm getting it to send mail decently, however there are times I push batches of e-mails to the mail server (50+ at a time).

The default configuration seems to be that it won't take more than 10 per connection.

I have chosen the "monolithic configuration file", however I cannot figure out how to:

- Change parameters, specifically "smtp_accept_queue_per_connection", as I don't know what file to edit, I've tried:

  - /etc/exim4/conf.d/main/00_local_settings
  - /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.template
  - /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.local

I also do not know how to verify that the change took place (exim read and understood the config) since I have to wait for our system to send > 10 e-mails, at which time it is losing critical messages.

Any idea where the correct configuration would be, and where I can set that value?

Comment: Alright, I found a way to check the config, but not to change it:

exim -bP | grep queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to regenerate and reload the configuration by running the command `systemctl reload exim4`.  The running configuration is the file `/var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated`.

I believe the property you want is `smtp_accept_max_per_connection`.  However, this defaults to 1000.  I believe this should be set in `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`, see the man page `update-exim4.conf` for details.

Try sending the batches over one connection rather than a large number of concurrent requests.  You may be hitting connection limits.

Try monitoring the file `/var/log/exim4/mainlog` when sending a batch of messages.  There should be messages telling you which limit has been hit there.  You can also use less or more to scan the log for a time when a batch stalled.

Full documentation is included in the [Exim4 specification](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/index.html).  This also has links to related documentation.

Comment: Bill, Thank you. In Ubuntu, the limit was defaulted to 10 per connection. I was sending over 50 to it which is what caused the issue.

Per your information, the config file that did it for me was "/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros", I was using the same file without the word "macros" at the end, hence why it failed. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Just a note that this approach also works for `smtp_accept_max`, which defaults to 20.